# Facebook oAuth request from multiple domains, redirecting to single URL

Tags: facebook, redirect, authentication

I deal with multiple customers who have their own websites and I'm launching a solution for them which requires Facebook login.

The problem is I want to have one page/plug-in in customer's site which allows their consumers to visit the site and click login. On successful login, I want Facebook to redirect the user to my site.

So, in short, the question is: can I have multiple domains (xyz.com, abc.in) sending oAuth requests to Facebook which contain the redirect URL mysite.com?

My app's settings are as follows:

App Domain: mysite.com
Site URL: www.mysite.com

I don't think Facebook allows me to add xyz.com, abc.in to App Domain.

I'm even willing to have a plug-in that's embeddable in different sites. Is this possible? If so, how can I achieve it?

On successful login/register the users should get redirected to mysite.com/fbcallback.php.

Answer (score 0):

> can I have multiple domains (xyz.com, abc.in) sending oAuth requests to Facebook which contain the redirect URL mysite.com?

No. You can use only subdomains of the domain you have set under “Website with Facebook login”.

> On successful login/register the users should get redirected to mysite.com/fbcallback.php.

If you want users to go to your own domain anyways, then you could send them to yourdomain.tld/facebook-login.php from your customers pages straight away, and handle the login call from there …?